# how to add various types of elements to dom reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

i have a toolbar component and 3 options to add text, image and video element to main page component, i write a click handle in main page component and pass this event handler to toolbar component.

my simple idea is that a switch with a parameter that define the type of element but i don't know how to render them.

how can i do this?

```
class ToolbarContainer extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div id="toolbarSection">
            <div class="option" onClick={this.props.handleActionsClick("image")}>new Image</div>
            <div class="option" onClick={this.props.handleActionsClick("text")}>new Text</div>
            <div class="option" onClick={this.props.handleActionsClick("shape")}>new Shape</div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

class Page extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    handleActionsClick(type){
        switch(type){
            case "image":
                //How can i render the <img/>?
            case "text":
            case "video":
        }
    }

    render() {
        return ();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`createElement`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html#createelement) instead, which is what JSX uses under the hood.

You can then pass in a custom component to the click handler or a string for the native elements like 'img'.

I am using [stateless component](https://medium.com/@joshblack/stateless-components-in-react-0-14-f9798f8b992d#.h8k2fzmoc) here but you can also just use classes if you need.

```
const ToolBarContainer = ({ handleActionsClick }) => (
    <div id="toolbarSection">
        <div class="option" onClick={handleActionsClick('img')}>new Image</div>
        <div class="option" onClick={handleActionsClick(Text)}>new Text</div>
        <div class="option" onClick={handleActionsClick(Shape)}>new Shape</div>
    </div>
);

class Page extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {};
        this.handleActionsClick = this.handleActionsClick.bind(this);
    }

    handleActionsClick(type){
        this.setState({ type });
    }

    render() {
        return React.createElement(this.state.type);
    }
}
```